# Helping on WSO2 IoT Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I install and configure WSO2 IoT Server version `3.3.0`. everything is OK and i enrolled 3 android devices in device management section.

However, after installing android agent on mobile device and after approximately half hour of inactivity when i open agent apk in mobile device i received a toast with this text `"Device Admin Disabled"` and i have to enter server address and then Organization and Username and Password again to see IoT Server again. In server management Dashboard mobile devices are in `"inactive"` status and server can't communicate with mobile device.

Also This happen every time i restart server and i have to follow above steps to communicate between mobile device and IoT Server.

My question, Is it normal??? Where I was wrong???

thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: could you give us, a log of the error that appear when wso2-iot server failed to connect.

Comment: there is no error, i told my session is timed out and i have to re-enter password in agent app again. i want to make the session between server and agent app not to be expired.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem here.

The apk that comes with the default IOT Server installation seems to be outdated.

You can download the newest release here:
https://github.com/wso2/cdmf-agent-android/releases/tag/v3.3.1

I've installed this version and now everything is fine.